# How to use Machine Learning to create a "Draw-A-Person Test"

Tags: machine-learning, ai-design, image-recognition, intelligence-testing

The process revolves around a child's drawing. Each part of each drawing corresponds to a score as in the [*Draw a Person Test* conceived by Dr. Florence Goodenough in 1926](https://pineight.com/mw/?title=Draw-A-Person_test). The goal of the machine is to measure a child's mental age through a figure drawing task.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very nice challenge!

As always, the hardest part is to get a labeled database (maybe by scrapping).

You'd probably need some thousands of drawings and their respective drawer age.

From there, you need to make an image regression model. [Here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/fastai-image-regression-age-prediction-based-on-image-68294d34f2ed) is a simple example that predicts age from a face photo. It's the same principle, but applied to another database, with other relevant features to be learned by the model.